# Laravel 5 - Download remote file with dynamic FTP info

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I can't seem to find any information about how one would download a remote file w/ Laravel 5 via FTP.

I tried using standard PHP

```
ftp_connect();
```

and I was met with this error...

```
Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\Tools\ftp_connect()
```

Is their a way to use this function, or is this something I should use a part of Laravel for?

I looked into using some part of Laravel for this, and most of the examples assume that you know the FTP ahead of time to update a config file somewhere...but the FTP info I use is given dynamically, so I guess I can't use that? Unless I'm supposed to use Config::set somehow?

I'm a little lost, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try using an existing library such as https://github.com/harishanchu/Laravel-FTP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably in a [namespaced](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) class, so PHP is looking for a `ftp_connect()` function inside that namespace (App\Http\Controllers\Tools).
To jump back to the global namespace, just add a backslash before the function:

```
\ftp_connect();
```

Answer (score 11):

This is how you create dynamic FTP drivers and use it.

```
$ftp = Storage::createFtpDriver([
                                 'host'     => 'ftp.example.com.br',
                                 'username' => 'ftpuser',
                                 'password' => 'password',
                                 'port'     => '21',
                                 //'root'     => '',
                                 //'passive'  => '',
                                 //'ssl'      => '',
                                 'timeout'  => '30',
                             ]); 
$filename = 'path/filename.txt'; 
$ftp->put($filename, 'some file content to write'); 
$filecontent = $ftp->get($filename);
```

Comment: Just a little mistake I forgot to put a $ on filename on the put method. $ftp->put($filename, 'some file content to write');

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I wish you were around a year ago :D

Comment: A year ago I even weren't a laravel programmer. hehe But the answer is for the future programmers.

Comment: @LeandroPerini ------ ErrorException
ftp_rawlist(): php_connect_nonb() failed: Operation now in progress (36)

Comment: @LeandroPerini Lol - the passive attribute is not working I think. Do you have any clue

Comment: @mujuonly have no idea, but there's a parameter that you can use if that's the case.